# Java Spring + Jersey subresource: inject constructor-arg at runtime

Tags: java, spring, jersey

I have the following method defined, returning a bean that represents a subresource locator (Jersey):

```
@Path("{slug}")
public PageResource page( 
        @PathParam("slug") String siteSlug) throws AppException { 

    siteService.getSiteBySlug(siteSlug); //Validate if exists, else throw error 

    return (PageResource) appContext.getBean("pageResource", siteSlug); 
}
```

`pageResource` has prototype scope defined in `applicationContext.xml`.

Question: what is the alternative way for injecting the bean into the current class, while passing the constructor-arg at runtime?
I'm not comfortable getting the bean explicitly from the application context.

Edit for @peeskillet:

The subresource:

```
public class PageResource {
    @Autowired
    IPageService pageService; 

    String siteSlug; 

    public void setPageService(IPageService pageService){
        this.pageService = pageService; 
    }

    public PageResource(){}

    public PageResource(String siteSlug){ //***Inject siteSlug from parent here***
        this.siteSlug = siteSlug; 
    }; 

    @POST
    @Path("/pages")
    @Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response createPage(@NotNull @Valid Page page) throws AppException{ 
        System.out.println(pageService);
        ObjectId pageId = pageService.createPage(page); 
        page.setId(pageId); 

        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.CREATED)// 201 
                .entity(page)
                .header("Location", 
                        "http://localhost:8000/zwoop-v001/sites/" + this.siteSlug + 
                        "/pages/" + page.getSlug()).build(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to inject `ResourceContext` into the main resource class and in the locator method return `context.getResource(PageResource.class)`

Comment: @peeskillet sorry for late reply. I need the ability to pass arguments to the subresource class constructor.

Comment: If you have Spring integration with Jersey configured correctly, i.e. you are able to inject your spring beans into Jersey resources, then using the above method should also inject into sub resources just fine.

Comment: Other than that, what arguments are you talking about? Just the bean to inject, or some other arguments?

Comment: @peeskillet I mean pass the argument from the parent class to the subresource's constructor (as `siteSlug` in the example above). Problem here is that the resource needs to be called at runtime, i.e. during the request, so I cannot define the constructor-args up front.

Comment: Sorry that doesn't really make much sense. Can you just post the sub-resource class

Comment: @peeskillet Updated with the subresource and commented the line of the constructor with argument. Does it make more sense now? In `applicationContext.xml` I cannot define a `constructor-arg` value / reference since it is only decided at runtime, i.e. depending on the request (the slug is a `PathParam`).

Comment: Path params can also be injected. Just add the `@PathParam` on the field and forget the constructor. Then use the method in my first comment. It should work.

Comment: @peeskillet Oh I see, thanks it works. If you post it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you can do is inject [`ResourceContext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ResourceContext.html), and resolve the sub-resource instance through that.

> The resource context can be utilized when instances of managed resource classes are to be returned by sub-resource locator methods. Such instances will be injected and managed within the declared scope just like instances of root resource classes.

As stated, you can obtain instances of your sub-resources classes, and all the injections will be handled

```
@Path("root")
public class Resource {

    @Context
    ResourceContext context;

    @Path("sub/{id}")
    public SubResource get() {
        return context.getResource(SubResource.class);
    }
}
```

`@PathParam`s are also resolved as injections into your sub-resource instance. So you could just do

```
class SubResource {

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @PathParam("id")
    long id;
}
```

And when the sub-resource instance gets resolved, it will be injected with the service and the path param.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the sub-resource having to know the name of the PathParam variable? This is the best example I've found so far but it still couples root resources with all its transitive sub-resources and requires duplicating the argument of `@PathParam` (I guess one way to avoid it is creating a constant though)

Comment: You would need to manually set it yourself with some kind of setter method. If there is no declaration, it's impossible for Jersey to know what to inject.